# Metodo de Fuerza Bruta en Java

Tags: java

tengo una duda con lo que viene ser el algortino de Fuerza Bruta la cual nose como implementarlo en mi codigo.

tengo que hacer un codigo usando Busqueda de Caracteres Mayusculas y Minusculas con fuerza bruta y casi que ya tengo el codigo pero buscando por internet para intentar guiarme habia encontrado algunos videos y guiandome de ellos hize este codigo

```
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Ingrese la Palabra: ");
        char Auxilar[] = teclado.nextLine().toCharArray();
        int Mayusculas = 0, Minusculas = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < Auxilar.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < Auxilar.length; j++) {
                switch (Auxilar[i]) {
                    //CONTADOR DE MAYUSCULAS
                    case 'A':
                        Mayusculas++;
                        break;
                    case 'E':
                        Mayusculas++;
                        break;
                    case 'I':
                        Mayusculas++;
                        break;
                    case 'O':
                        Mayusculas++;
                        break;
                    case 'U':
                        Mayusculas++;
                        break;

                    //CONTADOR DE MINUSCULAS
                    case 'a':
                        Minusculas++;
                        break;
                    case 'e':
                        Minusculas++;
                        break;
                    case 'i':
                        Minusculas++;
                        break;
                    case 'o':
                        Minusculas++;
                        break;
                    case 'u':
                        Minusculas++;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }//Imprime 
        System.out.println("\nCantidad de Masyuculas: " + Mayusculas + "\nCantidad de Minusculas: " + Minusculas);
```

Quizas me guie mal del video o algo he hecho mal, si pueden corregir mi codigo se los agradeceria pero mas que todo quiero saber como funciona y como puedo implementarlo en futuros codigos

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te sobra el bucle anidado

Comment: Pablo Lozano, si le quito el bucle anidado y le dejo solo 1 aun asi sigue siendo Fuerza Bruta?

Comment: Hacer algo por fuerza bruta simplemente significa hacerlo cubriendo todas las posibilidades. Por cierto, sólo estás mirando las vocales

Comment: si si, me falto especificar en mi pregunta que debo contabilizar las vocales Mayusculas o Minusculas. Muchas gracias Pablo